# Parse.com - Download Objects From Database - Show Progress With ProgressBlock

Tags: parse-platform, uiprogressview

I have Parse class called Product that has 238 rows. Note that this class is not the Parse.com implementation of Product, it is a custom class implemented by myself, as I didn't require all the columns Parse adds to their Product class.

The Product class has a Pointer column (basically a foreign key in SQL tables), called ShopId, because each product belongs to a specific Shop (I have a Parse class called Shop with an ObjectId column used in the Product Pointer.

My Product class also has a File column called imageFile that holds the image of the product.

I want to download all Products from a specific shop, unpackage their image file and put it in my Swift Product class which consists of the `PFObject` of the Parse Product, and a `UIImageView` and a `UIImage`. Here is my Product Class in Swift:

```
class Product {
    private var object: PFObject
    private var imageView: MMImageView!
    private var image: UIImage

    init(object: PFObject, image: UIImage) {
        self.object = object
        self.image = image
    }

    func getName() -> String {
        if let name = object["name"] as? String {
            return name
        } else {
            return "default"
        }
    }

    func setImageView(size: CGFloat, target: DressingRoomViewController) {
        self.imageView = MMImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size, size))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = self.image
        imageView.setName(object["category"] as! String)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGestureRecognizer =
        UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: "imageTapped:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func getImageView() -> MMImageView {
        return self.imageView
    }
}
```

I am currently downloading all the products just fine, and getting their image file and creating my Swift Products with their images. However my `UIProgressView` logic is slightly off. I have the `UIProgressView` running for every product, every time I unpackage the product image. I need to shift the Parse.com ProgressBlock out of the getProduct swift function and into the `loadProducts @IBAction`. When I try it, it causes a lot of errors before compilation. How do I shift the ProgressBlock up to the `loadProducts @IBAction`? Here is my current code:

```
//
//  ChooseShopViewController.swift
//  MirrorMirror
//
//  Created by Ben on 12/09/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Amber. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse

class ChooseShopViewController: UIViewController {

    var progressView: UIProgressView?
    private var allProducts: [Product] = []
    private var categories: [ProductCategory] = []

    @IBAction func loadProducts(sender: AnyObject) {
        let shopQuery = PFQuery(className:"Shop")
        shopQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("QjSbyC6k5C") {
            (glamour: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && glamour != nil {
                let query = PFQuery(className:"Product")
                query.whereKey("shopId", equalTo: glamour!)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    self.getAllProductsAndCategories(objects, error: error)
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create Progress View Control
        progressView = UIProgressView(  progressViewStyle:
                                        UIProgressViewStyle.Default)
        progressView?.center = self.view.center
        view.addSubview(progressView!)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(  segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "dressingRoom") {
            ShopDisplay.sharedInstance.setAllProducts(self.allProducts)
            ShopDisplay.sharedInstance.setAllProductCategories(self.categories)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    func getAllProductsAndCategories(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) {
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for product in objects {
                    self.getCategory(product)
                    self.getProduct(product)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func getCategory(product: PFObject) {
        if let category = product["category"] as? String {
            var alreadyThere: Bool = false
            for item in self.categories {
                if category == item.rawValue {
                    alreadyThere = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if alreadyThere == false {
                self.categories.append(ProductCategory(rawValue: category)!)
            }
        }
    }

    func getProduct(product: PFObject) {
        if let productImage = product["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
            productImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    self.allProducts.append(
                        Product(object: product, image: image!))
                }
                if let downloadError = error {
                    print(downloadError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, progressBlock: {
                (percentDone: Int32) -> Void in
                    self.progressView?.progress = Float(percentDone)
                if (percentDone == 100) {
                    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dressingRoom", sender: UIColor.greenColor())
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to not use the progressBlock, and instead to update my UIProgressView manually with a calculation. So here is the code. It's a little rusty. I could refactor now and maybe implement a calculated variable to make it cleaner. If my solution is a bad practice then I'm appreciative if that gets pointed out, and a better solution suggested (It doesn't seem good for performance to check the UIProgressView.progress value every iteration to perform the completion task of performing the segue).

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ChooseShopViewController: UIViewController {

    var progressView: UIProgressView?
    private var allProducts: [Product] = []
    private var categories: [ProductCategory] = []
    static var numberOfProducts: Float = 0

    @IBAction func loadProducts(sender: AnyObject) {
        let shopQuery = PFQuery(className:"Shop")
        shopQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("QjSbyC6k5C") {
            (glamour: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil && glamour != nil {
                let query = PFQuery(className:"Product")
                query.whereKey("shopId", equalTo: glamour!)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    ChooseShopViewController.numberOfProducts =
                        Float((objects?.count)!)
                    print(ChooseShopViewController.numberOfProducts)
                    self.getAllProductsAndCategories(objects, error: error)
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create Progress View Control
        progressView = UIProgressView(  progressViewStyle:
                                        UIProgressViewStyle.Default)
        progressView?.center = self.view.center
        progressView?.progress = 0.00
        view.addSubview(progressView!)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(  segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "dressingRoom") {
            ShopDisplay.sharedInstance.setAllProducts(self.allProducts)
            ShopDisplay.sharedInstance.setAllProductCategories(self.categories)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func getAllProductsAndCategories(objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) {
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for product in objects {
                    self.getCategory(product)
                    self.getProduct(product)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    func getCategory(product: PFObject) {
        if let category = product["category"] as? String {
            var alreadyThere: Bool = false
            for item in self.categories {
                if category == item.rawValue {
                    alreadyThere = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if alreadyThere == false {
                self.categories.append(ProductCategory(rawValue: category)!)
            }
        }
    }

    func getProduct(product: PFObject) {
        if let productImage = product["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
            productImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock ({
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = imageData {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    self.allProducts.append(
                        Product(object: product, image: image!))
                    self.progressView?.progress += (100.00 /
                        ChooseShopViewController.numberOfProducts) / 100.00
                    print(self.progressView?.progress)
                    if self.progressView?.progress == 1 {
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dressingRoom",
                            sender: UIColor.greenColor())
                    }
                }
                if let downloadError = error {
                    print(downloadError.localizedDescription)
                }

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the [Parse website](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files). It may be useful as it has a block that shows the percentage done that updates regularly during the download!

```
    let str = "Working at Parse is great!"
    let data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let file = PFFile(name:"resume.txt", data:data)
    file.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
          (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
          // Handle success or failure here ...
       }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: Int32) -> Void in

     // Update your progress spinner here. percentDone will be between 0 and 100.

 })
```

Did you find a better solution? besides this? I am trying to do something similar.

Comment: This seems to only work with PFFIle and not PFObject that contains a PFFIle.  Im stumped